# Best way to filter a dataset based on multiple filters

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I have a dataset containing a user's `GradeEntity` objects which contain references to their associated `SubjectEntity` instances. I need to allow the user to filter that dataset based on two options for now:

1. Subject Title
2. Date Range

Here's the logic I'm going for with the filtering process.
Let's say that the initial dataset contains two grade entities:

1. Grade(title: Math, date: 11th of July)
2. Grade(title: Math, date: 14th of July)

Now let's assume that the user sorts the grades based on i.e. "Math" but doesn't select a Date range yet. All respective grades are shown but now the user wants to apply a date range on the filtered dataset. He/She selects a range from 1st of July - 12th of July. So, now the user can only see the first grade entity. Let's now say that they want to change the date range filter from 1st of July - 15th of July. I'd like them to be able to now see both grades. That means that I can't just re-filter the filtered dataset like I'm doing in my current ViewModel code. Same issue when the user first filters based on date, then subject, and then chooses another subject. What is the best approach to such filtering processes?

Right now I'm using a shared `MutableLiveData<List<GradeEntity>>` variable, but that doesn't work for all the cases I mentioned above.

ViewModel.kt:

```
class GradesViewModel(private val database: AppDatabase) : ViewModel() {
    private val _grades: MutableLiveData<List<GradeEntity>> = MutableLiveData(emptyList())
    val grades: LiveData<List<GradeEntity>> = _grades
    private val _filteredGrades: MutableLiveData<List<GradeEntity>> = MutableLiveData(emptyList())
    val filteredGrades: LiveData<List<GradeEntity>> = _filteredGrades

    init {
        getGradesFromDB()
    }

    private fun getGradesFromDB() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val grades = database.getGradeDao().getAllGrades()
            if (grades.isNotEmpty() && grades != _grades.value) _grades.postValue(grades)
        }
    }

    fun getSubjectTitlesRelatedToGrades(): MutableSet<String> {
        val subjectTitles: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf("All Subjects")
        for (gradeEntity in grades.value!!) {
            subjectTitles.add(gradeEntity.subject.title)
        }
        return subjectTitles
    }

    fun filterGradesBasedOnSubject(subjectTitle: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            filterGradesBasedOnSubjectAsync(subjectTitle)
        }
    }

    fun filterGradesBasedOnDate(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            filterGradesBasedOnDateAsync(startDate, endDate)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun filterGradesBasedOnSubjectAsync(subjectTitle: String) {
        val filteredData = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (filteredGrades.value!!.isEmpty()) {
                grades.value?.stream()
                    ?.filter { gradeEntity -> gradeEntity.subject.title == subjectTitle }?.toList()
                    ?: emptyList()
            } else filteredGrades.value?.stream()
                ?.filter { gradeEntity -> gradeEntity.subject.title == subjectTitle }?.toList()
                ?: emptyList()
        }
        _filteredGrades.postValue(filteredData.await())
    }

    private suspend fun filterGradesBasedOnDateAsync(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
        val filteredData = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
            return@async if (filteredGrades.value!!.isEmpty()) {
                grades.value?.stream()
                    ?.filter { gradeEntity ->
                        formatter.parse(gradeEntity.formattedDateTime).after(startDate) &&
                                formatter.parse(gradeEntity.formattedDateTime).before(endDate)
                    }?.toList()
                    ?: emptyList()
            } else {
                filteredGrades.value?.stream()
                    ?.filter { gradeEntity ->
                        formatter.parse(gradeEntity.formattedDateTime).after(startDate) &&
                                formatter.parse(gradeEntity.formattedDateTime).before(endDate)
                    }?.toList()
                    ?: emptyList()
            }
        }
        _filteredGrades.postValue(filteredData.await())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be cleaner to only expose a single LiveData and keep your complete list of unfiltered results private. Then the Fragment/Activity only has to observe a single LiveData one time, and can separately modify which filters to apply. When filters change, have the ViewModel automatically update the value in the LiveData by refiltering the list of all values from scratch.

It would also be nice to have your backing data automatically update as well. To do this, you should add a repo/DAO function that returns a Flow. Basically a copy of `dao.getAllGrades()` that is *not* a suspend function and returns a `Flow<List<GradeEntity>>`. Let's call that `getAllGradesFlow()`.

To change the filters, we can expose properties for setting the current filters, and set them to trigger a re-filter of the backing data so the LiveData is automatically refreshed. And to reduce the number of functions/properties, we can use a `ClosedRange<Date>` as a property type for the dates filter. It makes it possible to check if a date is in between the two dates easy with the `in` operator, too. It's easy to specify with the `..` operator on the calling side.

I also want to mention, you don't have to specify `Dispatchers.IO` to call suspend functions in the DAO. Suspend functions by convention don't block so there's no need to specify any dispatcher to call them.

```
class GradesViewModel(private val database: AppDatabase) : ViewModel() {
    private var allGrades: List<GradeEntity> = emptyList()
    private val _grades: MutableLiveData<List<GradeEntity>> = MutableLiveData(emptyList())
    val grades: LiveData<List<GradeEntity>> = _grades
    var datesFilter: ClosedRange<Date>? by Delegates.observable(null) { _, _, _ -> onFilterChange() }
    var subjectTitleFilter: String? by Delegates.observable(null) { _, _, _ -> onFilterChange() }

    init {
        getGradesFromDB()
    }

    private fun getGradesFromDB() {
        database.getGradeDao().getAllGradesFlow()
            .onEach { 
                allGrades = it 
                publishFilteredGrades()
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    private fun onFilterChange() = viewModelScope.launch {
        publishFilteredGrades()
    }

    // Not related to your question but I simplified this.
    fun getSubjectTitlesRelatedToGrades(): Set<String> {
        return setOf("All Subjects") + allGrades.map { it.subject.title }
    }

    // Specifying a suspend function with dispatcher here because filtering 
    // a long list might be CPU heavy.
    private suspend fun publishFilteredGrades() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var filteredGrades = allGrades
        subjectTitleFilter?.let { subjectTitle ->
            filteredGrades = filteredGrades.filter { it.subject.title == subjectTitle }
        }
        datesFilter?.let { dates ->
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
            filteredGrades = filteredGrades.filter { 
                formatter.parse(it.formattedDateTime) in dates 
            }
        }
        _grades.postValue(filteredGrades)
    }
}
```

From the fragment, you only need to observe the single LiveData to update your list view. Change the two filter properties at will in any order, setting them to null to clear the filter.

Comment: This is an astonishingly good response, thank you for taking the time to write all this out. I actually had to research Flows, Delegates.observable and ClosedRange<T> and I learned so much already! Thank you again, this worked perfectly and I think I'll start using Flows more often now. P.S. Shouldn't the `allGrades` field be declared as a `var` since we're reassigning it inside the `getGradesFromDB`?

Comment: Yes, that should be `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `SwitchMap` operator on your `MutableLiveData`. A `SwitchMap` triggers the code again whenever the value of the `MutableLiveData` that it is called on changes.

for instance, let's say you wanted to filter based on date or subject only, you could use something like this:

```
private val _isDateSelected: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(false)

val currentResult = _isDateSelected.switchMap { dateIsSelected ->

   if(dateIsSelected) {

   // here the code that filters by date and returns a LiveData appears
  } else {

  // here the code that filters by subject and returns a LiveData appears 
  }
}

fun setSubjectSelectedFilter() {
  _isDateSelected = false
}

fun setDateSelectedFilter() {
  _isDateSelected = true
}
```

You can then observe this currentResult `LiveData` in your Views to get the filtered results by either the `Subject` or the `Date`. If you have any more queries, feel free to ask in comments :)